# Mamp Pro File Permissions

Tags: permissions

I use MAMP Pro 4 and Windows 10 to develop WordPress websites on my local computer. When an image is imported into the media library WordPress generates image sizes from this image and places them all in the wp-content/uploads folder, all standard WordPress functionality.

All the images are fine except the original image which does not have correct permissions. When I check Properties, Security of the image, it says "You must have Read permissions to view the properties of this object."

I then have to go through a 7 step process to add Full permissions for the computer user for this image. This is difficult when I have hundreds of images. There are no errors in the Apache log or the PHP file log.

I contacted MAMP support and although they are aware of the problem, they couldn't help me resolve it.

Comment: You should be able to use the `icacls` command line tool to set permissions in bulk (and superuser.com should have been able to tell you that without migrating you here). But if the MAMP team don't know how to fix the issue then I'd guess no one here will just know.

Comment: Finally found the solution on [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46750506/wrong-permissions-when-uploading-file-on-wordpress-windows-server-2012).